# canvas.height vs screen.availHeight shows different values

Tags: javascript

I've canvas.height and screen.availHeight reporting different values.
This is my code:

```
canvas.height = document.height || document.body.clientHeight;
canvas.width  = document.width  || document.body.clientWidth;
```

When I check with:

```
alert("canvas.width = " + canvas.width + 
"/n canvas.height = " + canvas.height + 
"/n screen.availHeight = " + screen.availHeight);
```

I get:

```
canvas.width       = 1904 which seems correct;
canvas.height      = 191  which is way out of order;
screen.availHeight = 1040 which seems correct.
```

Do I miss something or is there something wrong?

Comment: After some further research I find the following little style does the trick!
<style>html, body {width:100%; height:100%}</style>
After adding this, canvas.height = document.height reports correct window height.

Answer (score 0):

here

```
canvas.height = document.height || document.body.clientHeight;
canvas.width  = document.width  || document.body.clientWidth;
```

you set document in browser size http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp

In case

```
screen.availHeight
```

The availHeight property returns the height of the user's screen, in pixels, minus interface features like the Windows Taskbar.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_availheight.asp

You can use `Math.max(window.innerHeight, document.body.clientHeight)`